# Prevent text from being interpreted as a number

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a PHP/SQL app that processes invoices. Recently, I had an invoice number come in that is not being processed as text, rather as a large exponential number when I do an insert/update on associated SQL tables. For example, take an invoice number that looks like this: 123E456. PHP will try to convert this to an extremely large number due to the 'E' being bookended by numbers.

I am leaning towards this being a PHP issue because when I look at the SQL being sent to the server, it is being scripted without quotes, 123E456 rather than '123E456'.

I have tried multiple ways to try and force it to be text, but nothing seems to work.

- If I put single quotes around the string, I get double single quotes in the SQL.
- strval() also does not work
- the issue might be in the SQL interpreter, but not entirely sure

Right now, I am instructing my clerks to put a space between the E and the numbers, which works for now. But, I am hoping to address this specific issue in the code rather than have the clerk remember to manage it on their end.

Can anyone help with how to force this as being text in the SQL clause?

OK, the code is rather my own style and is based on retrieving a dummy record (the table has 178 columns) and then populating the values into the elements that need updated. It then creates the SQL from the array and does the update. Most of this is just pre-processing to get the values needed. The database being used is Oracle.

```
function processF0411Z1($id, $user){
    include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/truck/inc/base.inc.php';
    $b = '\' \'';
    $z = 0;
    $co = get_route_company($id);
    $usrsql='SELECT `userID` from `user` where `id` = ' . $user;
    $usr = openRecordset_Fetch_Assoc($usrsql);
    if($usr[0]==1)$userid = $usr[1]['userID'];
    else $userid = $_SESSION['username'];
    $jul = date2jul(getdate());
    $tjul= getJulTime(getdate());
    $sql = "SELECT a.`id`, a.`carrierInvoice`, a.`carrierNbr`, a.`ivd`, a.`dgl`, b.`bol`, b.`obj_acct`, b.`allocation` FROM `route13` a inner join `route131` b on(a.`id` = b.`id`)WHERE a.`id`=".$id;
    $myArr = openRecordset_Fetch_Assoc($sql);
    if(isset($myArr) && $myArr[0]>0){
        $carr = $myArr[1]['carrierNbr'];
        $carrsql = 'select `CarrierName` from `Carriers` where `CarrierNbr` = '. $carr;
        $carr_res = openRecordset_Fetch_Assoc($carrsql);
        if($carr_res[0]==1)$carrName = $carr_res[1]['CarrierName'];
        else $carrName = $carr;
        // get the next number in the EDI Batch sequence
        $nn = getJDEZFileNN();
        // get the base associated array of the F0411Z1 table
        $msSQL = 'SELECT * FROM PRODDTA.F59411Z1 WHERE VLEDUS=\'TRUCK\' AND VLEDBT=1';
        $F0411Z1 = oracle_fetch_array($msSQL);
        for($i=1;$i<=$myArr[0];$i++){
            // test to see if this record exists
            $tsql = "select * from PRODDTA.F0411Z1 where VLEDUS = '".strtoupper($user)."' and VLEDBT = ".$nn[1]['NNN006']." and VLEDLN = " .$i*1000;
            $tres = oracle_fetch_array($tsql);
            if($tres[0]>0){
                $dsql = "delete from PRODDTA.F0411Z1 where VLEDUS = '".strtoupper($user)."' and VLEDBT = ".$nn[1]['NNN006']." and VLEDLN = " .$i*1000;
                $count = oracle_update($dsql);
                if($count === $tres[0]){
                    $count = $count;
                }
            }
            $an8_sql = 'SELECT aban85 FROM PRODDTA.F0101 WHERE aban8='.$myArr[$i]['carrierNbr'];
            $aban85  = oracle_fetch_array($an8_sql);
            $dp = date_parse($myArr[$i]['ivd']);
            $dp1 = getDate(mktime(0,0,0,$dp['month'],$dp['day'],$dp['year']));
            $ivd = date2jul($dp1);//date('Y-M-d',mktime(0,0,0,$dp['month'],$dp['day'],$dp['year'])));
            $dp = date_parse($myArr[$i]['dgl']);
            $dp1 = getDate(mktime(0,0,0,$dp['month'],$dp['day'],$dp['year']));
            $inv_no = strval($myArr[$i]['carrierInvoice']);
            // index: ("VLEDUS", "VLEDBT", "VLEDTN", "VLEDLN")
            $gld = date2jul($dp1);//date('Y-M-d',mktime(0,0,0,$dp['month'],$dp['day'],$dp['year'])));
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLEDUS']  = '\''.strtoupper($user).'\'';//$_SESSION['userid'];
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLEDLN']  = $i*1000;
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLEDBT']  = $nn[1]['NNN006'];
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLAN8']   = $myArr[$i]['carrierNbr'];
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLPYE']   = $aban85[1]['ABAN85'];//$myArr[$i]['carrierNbr'];
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLDIVJ']  = $ivd;//$myArr[$i]['ivd'];
            //$F0411Z1[1]['VLDSVJ']  = $jul;
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLDGJ']   = $gld;
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLCO']    = $co;
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLKCO']   = $co;
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLAG']    = round(($myArr[$i]['allocation']*100),0);
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLAAP']   = round(($myArr[$i]['allocation']*100),0);
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLVINV']  = $inv_no;// <-- This element is the issue
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLRMK']   = (strlen($carrName)>30?substr($carrName,0,29):$carrName);
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLGLBA']   = '00573714';
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLMCU']   = '1';
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLTORG']  = $userid;//$_SESSION['userid'];
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLUSER']  = $userid;//$_SESSION['userid'];
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLPID']   = 'TRUCK';
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLUPMJ']  = $jul;
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLUPMT']  = $tjul;
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLJOBN']  = 'TRUCK';
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLURAB']  = $id;
            $F0411Z1[1]['VLURRF']  = $myArr[$i]['bol'];
            
            $z=1;
            
            for($x=1;$x<=$F0411Z1[0];$x++){
                $val1 = $F0411Z1[$x];
                // first element of array is the counter, skip it
                if($val1 != 1){
                    foreach($F0411Z1[1] as $val){
                        if($z==1){
                            $stmt = 'VALUES('.$val;
                            $z=99;
                        }
                        else{
                            if(!is_numeric($val))$val = '\''.$val.'\'';
                            $stmt .= ','.$val;
                        }
                    }
                    $stmt .= ')';
                    
                    //$msSQL = 'INSERT INTO PS_PRODUCTION.PRODDTA.F0411Z1 '.$stmt;
                    $msSQL = 'INSERT INTO PRODDTA.F0411Z1 '.$stmt;
                    
                    $count = oracle_update($msSQL);
                    if($count != 1) return 36;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else return 36;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please share your code around the INSERT

Comment: Share code, what is being defined doesn't reproduce, https://3v4l.org/hYroe.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the strval() method to cast the number as a string.

```
$number = 123E456;
$string = strval($number);
```

Or just force it to cast as a string

```
$string = (string) $number;
```

Comment: OP states this was already tried, `strval() also does not work`.